# Dropdown missing final click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Guys could someone please assist me to finish following:
I need to open dropdown and choose option. My code is:

```
WebElement sorter = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".column.medium-12 .row"));
    sorter.click();
    Actions keyDown = new Actions(driver);
    keyDown.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN)).perform();
```

I use following since there is no other way to open dropdown. After above code finishes, it looks like as on screenshot (stuck on first chosen option without confirmation). I am actually missing **confirmation click** but could not find solution. Please assist, thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the drowdown is just a normal `<select>` html element.

If that's the case, then you can iterate over the `<option>` elements of the drowdown and select the first.

```
WebElement sorter = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".column.medium-12 .row"));
sorter.click();
List<WebElement> elements = sorter.findElements(By.tagName("option");
WebElement option = elements.get(0);
option.click();
```

Comment: it is not normal **select** - that is why I am using **key.DoWN**

Comment: but is it a parent element with child elements in it? Then my approach still works, just the qualifiers need to be adjusted

Comment: it does work, but chosen is second option in dropdown. Not getting how to choose first. I thought that **get(0)** will choose first option but does not. Please assist and thank you

Comment: glad it helped.